# Using sed to remove both an opening and closing square bracket around a string

Tags: bash, regex, sed

I'm running this command in a bash shell on Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS. I'm attempting to remove both the `[` and `]` characters in one fell swoop, i.e. without having to pipe to sed a second time.

I know square brackets have special meaning in a regex so I'm escaping them by prepending with a backslash. The result I was expecting is just the string `123` but the square brackets remain and I'd love to know why!

```
~$ echo '[123]' | sed 's/[\[\]]//'
[123]
```

Comment: What I'm trying to ultimately achieve is to assign whatever's between the square brackets to a bash variable for use elsewhere in my bash script, so if there's a better way to achieve that (by using awk, maybe?), please let me know.

Comment: Just adding as a comment:

You can use bash's PE feature as in: 

`str='[123]'; str1=${str/\[/}; str2=${str1/\]}; echo $str2`

Comment: @val0x00ff - Pure bash substitution.. thanks! :) Learned something new.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

This is easy, if you follow the [manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#Character-Classes-and-Bracket-Expressions) carefully: all members inside a character class lose special meaning (with a few exceptions). And ] loses its special meaning if it is placed ***first*** in the list.  Try:

```
$ echo '[123]' | sed 's/[][]//g'
123
$
```

This says:

1. inside the *outer* [ brackets ], replace any of the included characters, namely:

   - `]` and
   - `[`
2. replace any of them by the empty string — hence the empty replacement string `//`,
3. replace them *everywhere* (*globally*) — hence the final `g`.

Again, `]` *must* be first in the class whenever it is included.

Comment: Live example: https://github.com/PHPExpertsInc/DockerUpgrade/blob/master/docker-images-update#L18

Comment: Is this behavior a characteristic of regex in general, or just sed?

Comment: @user1079505, unfortunately there is no such thing stricty as "regex in general".  Regex syntax has subtle variations in different environments (linux emacs, linux/unix utilities, shell, python, mongo, etc...).  However, where character classes are allowed in regex, this is the typical behavior.

Answer (score 13):

I'm not sure why that doesn't work but this does:

```
echo '[123]' | sed 's/\(\[\|\]\)//g'
```

or this:

```
echo '[123]' | sed -r 's/(\[|\])//g'
```

You can also try a different approach and match the string inside the brackets (assuming the string can be matched easily and is not defined by the brackets):

```
echo '[123]' | egrep -o "[0-9]+"
```

I'm having the same troubles with your original regex using `grep` so I suspect this is not just a `sed` thing.

Weirdly, these produce different results but one of them matches what you want:

```
echo '[123]' | egrep -o '[^][]+'
123

echo '[123]' | egrep -o '[^[]]+'
3]
```

Applying this to your original `sed` (and adding the `/g` modifier so it removes *both* brackets):

```
echo '[123]' | sed 's/[][]//g'
123
```

Comment: Your 3rd approach (egrep -o...) looks like the cleanest solution to my problem. I'll only ever have integers in between the square brackets (and sorry, I should have mentioned that in my question) so I shouldn't run into any oddities I think. Thanks!

Comment: You can also use `tr`: `echo '[123]' | tr -d '[]'` - avoids regexp confusions about escaping.

Comment: @James O'Gorman - Interesting. For some reason I thought that `tr` can only translate one character max at a time, but I was wrong. Thanks!

Comment: A simple solution must mean a simple problem. Thanks @JamesO'Gorman.

Answer (score 3):

To remove everything before and after the brackets :

```
$ echo '[123]' | sed 's/.*\[//;s/\].*//;'
123
```

If your data is like this always meaning starting and ending with square brackets:

```
$ echo '[123]' | sed 's/.//;s/.$//;'
123
```

Comment: The data I'm working with will always start and end with a square bracket yes. I'd still like to know why my solution wasn't working though. Any ideas? And is there a way to do this without specifying 2x regex's?

Comment: @Guru this solution worked from me, and as for Xhantar ,This is a really late reply, but what I can see from your code and the Bash Beginners guide at tldp.org , you were trying to do multiple search and replace, one for '[' and the other for ']' which wont work, to space out two different search and replace use the ";"  or the -e options. 's/<search>/<replace>/g ; s/<search>/<replace>/g'  OR sed -e 's/<search>/<replace>/g' -e 's/<search>/<replace>/g'

Answer (score 1):

You can escape the opening bracket using `\[`. For the closing bracket, use `[]]`.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a more complex string like 'abcdef[123]ghijk' you can also use internal bash command 'cut' to extract text only between square brackets:

```
$ echo 'abcdef[123]ghijk' | cut -d '[' -f 2 | cut -d ']' -f 1
123
```